# How can I use discrete fourier transformation on a set of complex values and real values and use that to determine the missing values?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I know that the time of the sample is

```
T = 9
```

and the sample rate is 0.5.

The 10 first values of the DFT-sequence are as follows:

```
{4, 1+3i, 0, 2, 0, -2i, (1-i)/4, 0, -1/25, 0...}
```

and I am to find out what the missing samples are (10 known samples, 18 samples in total).

How am I to approach this problem?

Comment: Why do you think that Mr. Fourier knows the missing numbers? They could be anything.

Comment: Would it help if I changed the phrasing to "The beginning 10 values of the DFT sequence are: {samples}?